# Is there something like a "hidden mode"?

Tags: window-manager

When somebody else uses my laptop, he can of course see all the windows I have currently open. I'm looking for a mode, which allows me to completely hide some windows but without closing them.

This could be useful if you have your private email and Facebook always opened in a browser window, but you don't want that coworkers could accidentally or intentionally open them when they do something at your laptop.

I'm not thinking about situations when somebody really wants to spy. I think about situations when - for example - a coworker explains you something at your laptop and you don't want him to accidentally see your private mails when he - for example - switches into the browser.

Comment: The only way you could stop them from intentionally opening certain windows is by password protecting them somehow, which I do t think is possible. You could enable the Guest account and switch to that; would that be a workable option?

Comment: A little more information as to *what* you need to share on your Mac would be helpful.  A guest account is a great option, you can set certain folders to be viewed by others.  If that is desirable, then someone can draft an appropriate answer.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [GhostTile](http://ghosttile.kernelpanic.im/) for this. It is paid app though. It allows you hide applications from Dock, Cmd+Tab, Force Quit Applications, etc. You can configure system-wide shortcut key to make the hidden apps visible.

[image]

Comment: That comes close to what I'm looking for. Is it also possible to attach just ONE window of an app into the ghost tile (for example, a browser windows where I have some private stuff opened)?

Comment: There are plenty of browsers, you could use a different one for your private stuff :)